# what is sub-linear convergence called?

Tags: numerical-methods, convergence-divergence, approximation-theory

What is sub-linear reciprocal convergence called?  Would it be called parabolic convergence? For example, consider the series:

$1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{8}...$

When you sum up such a series, the result gets arbitrarily large.  But if you have an alternating sum the result is defined, but convergence is slow.

$\frac{\pi}{4}=1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{11}+\frac{1}{13}-\frac{1}{17}...$

Numerical convergence for such an alternating series can be greatly speeded up by using binomial weightings on the last n+1 approximations.   My observation is that convergence becomes exponential.  What would this be called?

$\sum_{i=0}^{n} S_{m+i} \times 2^{-n} \times {n \choose i}$

```
For example, if you use the series for Pi, for the first 10 terms you get:
0  +4/1  4.000000000000000000000000000
1  -4/3  2.666666666666666666666666667
2  +4/5  3.466666666666666666666666667
3  -4/7  2.895238095238095238095238095  binomial weightings
4  +4/9  3.339682539682539682539682540   1/64
5  -4/11 2.976046176046176046176046176   6/64
6  +4/13 3.283738483738483738483738484  15/64
7  -4/15 3.017071817071817071817071817  20/64
8  +4/17 3.252365934718875895346483582  15/64
9  -4/19 3.041839618929402211135957266   6/64
10 +4/21 3.232315809405592687326433456   1/64
A binomial weighting for approximations 4..10 gives a much more accurate result
3.141598683394349029023951625
```

Comment: The term I was looking for was harmonic series.  I don't know what the speedup mechanism for convergence with alternating harmonic series is called.